# Efficient multiple subqueries from multiple tables with OR and ORDER BY/LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, query-performance

Question covers doubts on efficient SQL query for multiple subqueries:

I have 3 tables. I want to get details from table 1, based on filtering done from table 2 and table 3. Currently I am using IN clause on table 2 and table 3 but it takes around 6 seconds for 2M users. I tried join also but it was slower than subquery.

Table1:

mysql> describe users;

```
  Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default   
| uuid                 | varchar(36)      | NO   | PRI | NULL  
| firstname            | varchar(512)     | YES  |     | NULL 
| status               | varchar(512)     | YES  |     | NULL 
| createdAt            | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Table 2:

describe homes;

```
| Field                    | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra
| uuid                     | varchar(50)      | NO   | PRI | NULL 
| phoneNumberHash          | varchar(512)     | YES  | MUL | NULL 
| secondaryPhoneNumberHash | varchar(512)     | YES  | MUL | NULL
```

Table 3:

describe utility_tags:

```
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | 
| tag_name   | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
| tag_value  | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    | 
| user_id    | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
```

I have index on all the required fields ie.

- User Table : Index on uuid
- Home Table : Separate Index on phoneNumberHash and secondaryPhoneNumberHash
- Utility_Tags: Separate Index on tag_name and tag_value

Query I am running:

```
SELECT uuid, firstname 
FROM users 
WHERE ( uuid in (
   SELECT `uuid` 
   FROM `homes` 
   WHERE ( ( `phoneNumberHash` = '02c' OR `secondaryPhoneNumberHash` = '02c' ))
 ) 
 OR uuid in (
   SELECT `user_id` 
   FROM `utility_tags`  
   WHERE  ( `tag_name` = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER' AND `tag_value`= '13' )
 )) 
 AND `status` != 'DELETED' 
 ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

The query is slow and takes around 6 sec when there are 2M rows in user and homes table.

I tried join query:

```
SELECT users.uuid, firstname 
FROM users inner join homes  on homes.uuid=users.uuid 
inner join utility_tags on utility_tags.user_id=users.uuid 
WHERE  ( phoneNumberHash = '02c' OR secondaryPhoneNumberHash = '02cd0' ) 
   OR  ( tag_name = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER' AND tag_value= '1311851988' ) 
AND `status` != 'DELETED' 
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

This takes around 30 seconds.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: An index on `uuid,phoneNumberHash,secondaryPhoneNumberHash,tag_name,tag_value`, is different than separate indexes on `uuid`, `phoneNumberHash`, etc... Do you have indexes starting with `phoneNumberHash` and/or `secondaryPhoneNumberHash`?

Comment: Be sure you have indexes for the fields you are putting in **where** conditions. if you dont have any , it could be better and good practice first explan plain object and see if there is some full table scan , after that create the indexes .

Comment: Thanks @Uueerdo for the edits. I have edited the question. I have separate starting index for phoneNumberHash and secondaryPhoneNumberHash.

Comment: It looks to me like you want any ten rows matching certain criteria. It looks like you want those rows to be selected by the MySql server at its discretion.  I mention this because the ordering of result sets is formally unpredictable unless you use `ORDER BY`.  If you're getting the rows you think you should get from the queries you showed, it's a **happy accident.**  Could you tell us more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @O.Jones for the edits, you are right about the happy accident part. Actually I have 1 more column named "createdAt" in users table and I order by createdAt column in the final query. I removed that part to simplify the question.

Comment: I figured you did that. With respect you oversimplified the question. `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` is a grotesquely inefficient antipattern in MySQL queries. Please [edit] your question to show that, or you may not get useful answers.  Also, it's rare that indexes on individual columns help the performance of complex queries.

Comment: MySQL pretty much ignores indexes when you have an `OR`, you might see a performance increase if your first subquery is separated out into two (one with a half of it's OR).

Comment: @O.Jones I have updated the question, please check, sorry for not adding it earlier thanks

Comment: @Uueerdo I dont think that statement is correct. Earlier I didnt have index on secondaryPhoneNumberHash and my subquery was very slow, after I added starting index on secondaryPhoneNumberHash, my subquery became very fast.

Comment: UUIDs can be terribly [_inefficient_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) when the data gets bigger than the cache.  Which Engine are you using?  How much RAM?  What is cache size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting certain rows from your `users` table based on matches in your other tables.  You're using a complex `IN( ... )` clause for that.

Let's look at the contents of that clause for optimization possibilities.  Here's one way you generate a set of `uuid` values.

```
SELECT uuid 
  FROM homes 
 WHERE phoneNumberHash = '02c' 
    OR secondaryPhoneNumberHash = '02c'
```

Here's the other

```
 SELECT user_id 
   FROM utility_tags  
  WHERE tag_name = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER' 
   AND tag_value= '13'
```

Let's recast all this as a `UNION` of several sets of `uuid` values, like this.

```
             SELECT uuid FROM homes WHERE phoneNumberHash = '02c'
             UNION 
             SELECT uuid FROM homes WHERE secondaryPhoneNumberHash = '02c'
             UNION 
             SELECT user_id AS uuid
               FROM utility_tags
              WHERE tag_name = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER' 
                AND tag_value= '13'
```

That union of three queries does the same thing as all your `OR` clauses. The first two of those queries should (if you're using InnoDB) be optimized by the indexes on `phoneNumberHash` and `secondaryPhoneNumberHash` respectively. The third query in that union needs a compound index on `(tag_name, tag_value, user_id)` to perform efficiently.

The cool thing about `UNION` is it does the same sort of set creation as `OR`, but lets you write queries within the `UNION` that are more likely to use indexes.  I suggest you experiment with this `UNION` query and appropriate indexes until you're happy with its performance.  Then you can use it in your outer query.

(It's possible that the query planner has become smart enough to handle `phoneNumberHash = '02c' OR secondaryPhoneNumberHash = '02c'` as a UNION all by itself, exploiting your two indexes one after the other. Recent MySQL versions have made great progress in query planning.)

So that leaves us with the outer query:

```
SELECT uuid, firstname 
  FROM users 
 WHERE matching uuids
   AND status != 'DELETED' 
 ORDER BY createdAt DESC
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This is hard to make [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  The query planner doesn't like `!=` operators. It likes `=` best because index equality scans are cheap. It likes `<`, `<=`, `>=`, and `>` OK because range scans are almost as cheap.  But you're stuck with `!=`.

Also, the query planner **hates** `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` because it has to sort a whole mess of rows just to discard all except a tiny number.

The following compound covering index MAY optimize this query: `(createdAt, status, uuid, firstname)`. The query planner may be able to dodge the separate `ORDER BY` if it has an index that provides both the match criteria and the needed results. It's also possible that this index will be better. `(createdAt, status, uuid, status, firstname)` You'll need to try them both. Don't keep them both, only the one that helps best.

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT u.uuid, u.firstname 
  FROM users u 
  JOIN (
             SELECT uuid FROM homes WHERE phoneNumberHash = '02c'
             UNION 
             SELECT uuid FROM homes WHERE secondaryPhoneNumberHash = '02c'
             UNION 
             SELECT user_id AS uuid
               FROM utility_tags
              WHERE tag_name = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER' 
                AND tag_value= '13'
       ) s ON s.uuid = u.uuid
 WHERE status != 'DELETED' 
 ORDER BY createdAt DESC
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Things get interesting on megarow tables when you want subsecond query response.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a fine reference for this stuff.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Also thanks for explaining this in detail. Valuable lesson learnt on joins and sub queries.

Comment: Happy to help! Can you please enter a comment with your results? How much faster? What indexes actually worked for you?  That way others can learn from your experience. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar query but with 5 unions. Managed to reduce the response time from 900ms to 1ms. main table has 75k+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you're selecting from `users` *first* - move it to last so its index can be used (subqueries can't be indexed).

Also, SQL `OR` is notorious, mainly because (almost always) at most 1 index can be used.

1. Select from the subquery *first*, so the index into `users` can be used
2. Ensure there are indexes on all looked-up columns, ie `(uuid)`, `(phoneNumberHash)`, `(secondaryPhoneNumberHash)` and `(tag_name, tag_value)`
3. Break up your query to eradicate `OR`

Try this:

```
SELECT uuid, firstname 
FROM (
    SELECT uuid
    FROM homes
    WHERE phoneNumberHash = '02c'
    UNION
    SELECT uuid
    FROM homes
    WHERE secondaryPhoneNumberHash = '02c'
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM utility_tags 
    WHERE tag_name = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER'
    AND tag_value = 13
) x
JOIN users ON users.uuid = x.uuid
   AND status != 'DELETED' 
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Notice also that the test for `status != 'DELETED'` is in the *join* condition (not the `WHERE` clause), so it's executed at join time, not post-join, which will boost performance especially if there are a lot of deleted users.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have fixed my query to use joins now. Marked the other answer as correct as it came earlier.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg I am curious - which query performs better? Mine or his?